# BEGIN and END in Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I'm trying to obtain some data of specific pattern from a text file in `BEGIN` block and print them in the `END` block, as follows:

```
perl -0777wnE'
BEGIN{
    while(/<mark>(.*?)<\/mark>/g){
        $hw=$1; 
        $seen{$hw}++;
    }
} 
END{
    for $key (keys %seen){
        say "$key";
    }
}
' "demo.txt" > "demo2.txt"
```

But it doesn't print anything into the demo2.txt file, and it gives the following warning:

> Use of uninitialized value $_ in pattern match (m//) at -e line 3.

But if I put the `while` block outside of `BEGIN` block , like this:

```
perl -0777wnE'
while(/<mark>(.*?)<\/mark>/g){
    $hw=$1; 
    $seen{$hw}++;
}
END{
    for $key (keys %seen){
        say "$key";
    }
}
' "demo.txt" > "demo2.txt"
```

Then it gets the expected results.

Comment: Get rid of `n` switch for starters

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When the BEGIN block runs (i.e. when compiling the source code), the file handle is not yet opened. You can verify it with

```
perl -nE 'BEGIN { say $ARGV }'
```

Comment: Thanks @choroba I'm wondering what if I need to get some data ready first from the whole document before any real data processing, like substitution, etc.

Comment: @jonah_w: Then don't use the `-n` and iterate the files manually as many times as you need.

Comment: I tried putting `while(/<mark>(.*?)<\/mark>/g)` in the `END` block, it gives the same warning. Only this time $ARGV has a value when in `END`.

Comment: Yes, but ARGV is at EOF in the END block when `-n` or `-p` is present.